# How do you initialize static map of private member function pointers?

Tags: c++, class, static-members, stdmap, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to make a MARIE code simulator, or whatever you would call it, and I'm trying to avoid a long switch case to access some private functions in the class.

MARIEapp.h:

```
MARIEapp.h{
public:
   typedef void (MARIEapp::*Instruction)();
private:
   static std::map<char, Instruction> MARIEinstruction;
   void JnS();
   void Load();
   void Store();
   void Add();
   void Subt();
   void Input();
   void Output();
   void Halt();
   void Skipcond();
   void Jump();
   void Clear();
   void AddI();
   void JumpI();
   void LoadI();
   void StoreI();
};
```

MARIEapp.cpp:

```
static std::map<char, MARIEapp::Instruction> MARIEinstruction = {
    { '0', &MARIEapp::JnS },
    { '1', &MARIEapp::Load },
    { '2', &MARIEapp::Store },
    { '3', &MARIEapp::Add },
    { '4', &MARIEapp::Subt },
    { '5', &MARIEapp::Input },
    { '6', &MARIEapp::Output },
    { '7', &MARIEapp::Halt },
    { '8', &MARIEapp::Skipcond },
    { '9', &MARIEapp::Jump },
    { 'A', &MARIEapp::Clear },
    { 'B', &MARIEapp::AddI },
    { 'C', &MARIEapp::JumpI },
    { 'D', &MARIEapp::LoadI },
    { 'E', &MARIEapp::StoreI }
};
```

The long list of void functions access private members and are properly defined in the cpp file

The problem is that, when initializing the MARIEinstruction map, I get an error that says that those functions are not accessible. I know it's because they're private, and I can fix this by just making them public.

Is there a way I can do this and leave these all as private?
Also are there any other ways you recommend I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, you're allowed to name private members from inside the initializer of a static class member, just like from inside the definition of a member function.

Your trouble here is that you're not defining the static class member.  You're defining an unrelated global object named `MARIEinstruction`.  To define the class member, you must use the class member access syntax `MARIEapp::MARIEinstruction`.  Also, don't put the `static` keyword on the definition, just on the declaration.

```
std::map<char, MARIEapp::Instruction> MARIEapp::MARIEinstruction = {
    { '0', &MARIEapp::JnS },
    { '1', &MARIEapp::Load },
    { '2', &MARIEapp::Store },
    { '3', &MARIEapp::Add },
    { '4', &MARIEapp::Subt },
    { '5', &MARIEapp::Input },
    { '6', &MARIEapp::Output },
    { '7', &MARIEapp::Halt },
    { '8', &MARIEapp::Skipcond },
    { '9', &MARIEapp::Jump },
    { 'A', &MARIEapp::Clear },
    { 'B', &MARIEapp::AddI },
    { 'C', &MARIEapp::JumpI },
    { 'D', &MARIEapp::LoadI },
    { 'E', &MARIEapp::StoreI }
};
```

Comment: You also want to label the map `const`  You probably don't want to change it.

Comment: Thanks, that helped, but now how would i do this with it being a const?